# How to remove certain characters in a string without creating blank spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an api that receives inputs for example;

`@message.to = params[:to]`

ideally to should be sent inputs like `"256773485930"` as a telephone number.
However, some users prefer to send numbers like `"+256773485930"`

I tried using `@message.to = params[:to].gsub("+", "")` but it create an input like this

```
" 256773485930"
```

adding a space on the new string. 
How do i remove the `+` if its there without adding a space in front of the string?

Comment: Why not just strip all non-numerical characters? `s.gsub(/\D/, '')`

Comment: Statement is wrong. `"+256773485930".gsub("+", "")` does not return `" 256773485930"`.

Comment: That is what i got as the error because in the it created a space in the url where it was placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gsub` should work but probably the input string also has a space in front so you can do `params[:to].strip.gsub("+", "")` this removes the spaces before and after the string.

More robust if you want to keep digits only is `params[:to].gsub(/[^\d]/,"")`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with a `Regexp`:

> If a `Regexp` is supplied, the matching portion of the string is returned.

Example:

```
"+256773485930"[/\d+/] #=> "256773485930"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. Google open sourced their [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) a while ago, which is able to parse phone numbers in many formats and then again output them in different standardised formats. The library was ported to a [Ruby Gem named global_phone](https://github.com/sstephenson/global_phone). I would suggest to use this Gem, because it handles numerous edge cases that we probably even don't think of. Example usage:

```
require 'global_phone'
GlobalPhone.db_path = 'global_phone.json'   # see Github page for more info

# somewhere else
@message.to = GlobalPhone.normalize(params[:to])
```

This will convert every number to the normalized E.164 international string format for telephone numbers. While this means that the converted phone numbers will actually start with a `+`, this is the "correct" and standard way to store phone numbers.